# Bicycle computers with nonvolatile memory

Tags: bike-computer, battery

The one thing that keeps me from pulling the trigger on some bike computer is the lack of information about the odometer, the lifetime mileage on the bicycle. When you change the battery in your car, your electronic dash odometer doesn't go to zero. It would be stupid. When my Samsung Note 4  battery dies right in the middle of something, I remove and replace with my hot spare and it remembers right where it left off. I've been told not all bike computers are nonvolatile like this.

Which cycle computers are able to remember information when the battery is changed? Or better yet, is there someplace in the spec sheet or other way to find out if it has non-volatile memory without buying it?

Comment: Most log rides with software (e.g., strava) and let the software provide the summaries such as overall mileage

Comment: The several simple bike "computers" I've had all would reset when you remove the battery.  The solution to this was to write down the mileage before removing the battery.  I'd write it on the owner's manual, except that the manuals have gotten cheesier and cheesier over the years.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is structured as a poll for people's opinions.

Comment: I hesitate to close it as I believe there is a very valid question in there - what bike computers remember the odo when the battery is changed?  Its kind of shopping advise, but its also a question others might benefit knowing the answer to.

Comment: I think it's a valid question. I bought a cheap computer especially for recording ODO, for easier maintenance (e.g. to see how long a chain lasts). My proper GPS is also used for walking so it would be difficult to extract only the bike bits. The computer resets to zero, but it allows me to set the ODO value in the same way as I can set the time, so I can write it down before battery change and set it afterwards. However, it sometimes loses power unexpectedly (vibrations, water..), so one with permanent memory would be better. It's a no-name device, branded to a local bike shop, ca 6 UK pound.

Comment: One problem is this:  Your basic bike (non-GPS) bike computers have gotten cheesier and cheesier over the past 20 years or so, and so one must carefully pick one with appropriate features (mainly reliability).  Whether or not they have persistent memory is secondary to more critical features.

Comment: What X has Y feature is the definition of a shopping question. Usefulness of the answer is secondary. It might be best for the longtimers to edit this question into something 1) even more useful and 2) less of a shopping question (i.e., how can one tell which units have non-volatile memory).

Comment: It may not be a big deal at all.  I have a Cateye Mity 8 I bought in 2011 and it is still working with its original battery.  I do take bragging pictures of it regularly though.

Comment: Whats the point of a bike odometer that can't be reset? For one, tampering with such a thing is trivial -- disconnect the pickup or just throw out the meter. And mileage isn't a good measure of how far a bike is into its lifespan. On a car, both of these don't happen -- car odometers are decent indicators of how far a car is into its lifespan, and they're hard to tamper with. And very few riders probably go by mileage for maintenance rather than time. As for the car analogy, depending on your car, the trip computer will be reset on battery disconnect (but not the odometer, obviously).

Comment: I don't blame you for wanting a computer with non-volatile memory, but I have come up with a different solution to the same problem.  I keep a log of my rides on a spreadsheet, even though I use Strava, because sometimes the phone's battery dies, but the computer hardly ever does.  At the end of the ride I email the data from the computer to myself.  I include the odometer reading in the data.  That way if the computer's battery dies suddenly, then I can easily reset the odometer to the correct value.  The battery has not died suddenly since I started changing the battery annually though.

Answer (score 7):

I am also searching for a computer with non-volatile memory.

Following Sigma computers **[retain data](https://www.sigmasport.com/en/produkte/fahrrad-computer/wired/wired/bc1416?submenu=manuals)**:

- BC 14.16
- BC 16.16
- BC 14.16 STS
- BC 16.16 STS
- BC 23.16 STS
- BC 10.0 WR
- BC 10.0 WL
- BC 12.0 WR
- BC 12.0 WL
- BC 14.0 WL
- BC 14.0 WR

[According to Sigma these computers](https://www.sigmasport.com/en/produkte/fahrrad-computer/wireless/wireless/bc716ats/design-technology?submenu=manuals) **do not save** your values after a battery change (however, you can manually set the odometer):

- BC 5.16
- BC 7.16
- BC 7.16 ATS
- BC 9.16
- BC 9.16 ATS
- PURE 1 (according to the reply from Sigma customer service)
- BC 5.0 WR
- BC 5.0 WL
- BC 8.0 WR
- BC 8.0 WL

[According to VDO](http://www.cycleparts.de/en/products/m1/functions.html) M Zero **loses memory** after battery change.

But following **VDO models have non-volatile memory**:

- M1.1 WR/WL
- M2.1 WR/WL
- M3.1 WR/WL
- M4.1 WR/WL
- M5
- M6.1
- M7 GPS

[All settings must be re-entered](https://www.prophete.de/en/media/downloads.php) for bike computers Prophete 0511, 0512, 0531 after the batteries have been inserted.

Comment: I _think_ many such bike computers will retain the data even without non-volatile memory _if the battery is changed quickly_ (within seconds). Like many digital watches. I certainly managed to do it on a very old (20y+) Sigma 7.

Comment: I agree that it is possible to change the battery quickly but what if I drop the new battery during the change or the battery depletes during the winter. I definitely wouldn't want to describe to my dad on the phone how to reconfigure his bicycle computer after such an event. This problem should and has been solved by the manufacturers and not by the users. Therefore, we must demand to be informed about the possible choices.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Sigma computers, while not retaining the odometer value, allow you to set it manually. I edited, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Several Sigma bike computers with model numbers that start with BC16 have persistent memory for wheel size and odometer.

I have been personally using these because they are effortless way of keeping track of totals and do not lose count when battery runs out, very accurate when calibrated and work where GPS does not.

Answer (score 1):

I always log my rides on Strava.  By spending a couple minutes to set up any bike I own, they show up in a dropdown list at the end of each ride.

[image]

Yes - I have one bike that is still in single digits.  "Company bike" refers to two owned by my workplace, and "Someone else's bike" is a placeholder for if I ride another bike.  I don't record the second bike if I'm ghost riding two.